# Installing Netgear WG311v3 PCI adapter

Tags: 10.10, wireless, drivers

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 on Atom D410 desktop (I am new to Ubuntu).

Every thing is working fine except my Netgear wireless WG311v3 PCI adapter. Is there any way to install the driver a driver for it? Or does Ubuntu not support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to install the windows drivers using ndiswrapper for this specific device.

But apparently

> there is no driver that will allow WPA
>   encryption. You will have to run
>   either using WEP or no encryption

For a guide on how to get your wireless adapter working, there is documentation in the [Ubuntu Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Netgear_WG311_v3)